# Stabilizing the latency. Many TCP Bad CheckSum packets captured by Wireshark

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, driver

I am coding some network software and trying to minimize and stabilize the latency. 
I came up with the thing that in most cases the latency to remote host ( send message and receive the ACK by some protocol ) is about 2 ms, but sometimes there are some fluctuations(instantly goes to 40ms and then back to 2 ms), which i cannot explain(  code is pretty simple and straightforward), so i started blaming the network card. First thing I found out through WireShark is that there is a lot of TCP Bad Checksum packets? Is it possible that it is the case? This is the first thing, after all i found out that my intel network card is detected by OS ( Linux SLED 11 ) improperly. lspci command outputs wrong NIC information. How can i fix it? Should I reinstall the driver? If so how can i do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Checksum_Verification) about checksum errors.  Checksums are sometimes calculated in hardware by your NIC, so wireshark will see it incorrectly even if it is correct on the wire.

Unless you have a direct point to point network connection, without any routers or switches in between, you aren't going to be able to remove all variation in latency.  Even with a direct connection you won't be able to unless you are running a real time operating system on both ends.  Queues getting full, memory getting paged in and out, higher priority tasks running, and many other things affect your latency.  You need to look into jitter buffers and sliding window protocols if you want to minimize the harmful effects of jitter.

Also, the lspci command shows what chipset is actually detected on the pci bus, and really has nothing to do with the driver it is using.  Manufacturers change chipsets occasionally, and they are not always a good match to the brand on the box.  Depending on the history of the driver, the name won't necessarily match your expectations.  If traffic is passing, you almost certainly are using the right driver.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So i should not bother myself with Checksums error and more focus on the code actually? I have direct connection to the server and running realtime OS ( using realtime Java also ). Maybe you can recommend some practices,patterns how to efficiently organize client side ( for instance I need to read much more data and send back to server something rarely )?

Comment: There are always tradeoffs between latency, jitter, and throughput, and how to optimize depends on the application. What are you using it for?

Comment: I am using it for trade application. Retrieving continuously data from trade server, process each message and sometimes send it back to the server some instructions. I am trying to find out good architecture design, but I cannot find any materials or previous experience. Now I came up with single thread(realtime highest priority) -> i read ByteBuffer,unmarshal message and send it to the algorithm(process about 50mk sec). So all the process is sync. Maybe it is more appropriate to have 2 threads? One for I/O and one for algorithm and a blocking queue between them?

Comment: So i am trying to tune now the network latency,cause i am pretty confident with the algorithm ( it process time is pretty stable and appropriate for me, 50mksec )

Comment: That application is not sensitive to jitter like, for example, video or audio streams, so I wouldn't worry too much about the occasional 40ms.  The question is if throughput or latency is more important to you.  You can probably get more throughput by processing the previous data in a separate thread while you're receiving the next data, because the processor can take advantage of gaps between the packets.  If turnaround is more important than trades per second, your current single-threaded architecture is usually better because you avoid context switching overhead.

Comment: Maybe you can recommend some practices/articles how to tune OS, NIC for better latency?

Comment: actually, that 40ms is quiet bothering me. For instance, I am sending 6 packets ( with 100ms delay between each other ) and can have such a picture in latency(ms) 1.5 2 2.1 2 40 1.8 4